# Ubuntu has wrong versions of packages can't upgrade python

Tags: python, apt, ubuntu-22.04

I've just upgraded my Ubuntu from focal(20.04) to jammy(22.04), and now my python is broken. which causes a lot of headache all over, like Apt wont update and some applications won't start.

`libpython3.10 : Depends: libpython3.10-stdlib (= 3.10.6-1~22.04.2) but 3.10.9-1+focal2 is to be installed`

As the ubuntu package documentation 3.10.6.1 is the current (jammy) version. but why does it try to install a focal package (3.10.9.1 = lunar(23.04)).

i have tried to install python 3.11 instead (i used to run 3.10). but Apt still throws this error.

sources.list:

```
deb https://ftp.snt.utwente.nl/pub/os/linux/ubuntu/ jammy main restricted  
deb-src https://ftp.snt.utwente.nl/pub/os/linux/ubuntu/ jammy universe main multiverse restricted  
deb https://ftp.snt.utwente.nl/pub/os/linux/ubuntu/ jammy-updates main restricted  
deb-src https://ftp.snt.utwente.nl/pub/os/linux/ubuntu/ jammy-updates universe main multiverse restricted  
deb https://ftp.snt.utwente.nl/pub/os/linux/ubuntu/ jammy universe  
deb https://ftp.snt.utwente.nl/pub/os/linux/ubuntu/ jammy-updates universe  
deb https://ftp.snt.utwente.nl/pub/os/linux/ubuntu/ jammy multiverse  
deb https://ftp.snt.utwente.nl/pub/os/linux/ubuntu/ jammy-updates multiverse  
deb-src https://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates multiverse  
deb https://ftp.snt.utwente.nl/pub/os/linux/ubuntu/ jammy-backports main restricted universe multiverse  
deb-src https://ftp.snt.utwente.nl/pub/os/linux/ubuntu/ jammy-backports main restricted universe multiverse  
deb-src https://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-backports main restricted universe multiverse  
deb https://ftp.snt.utwente.nl/pub/os/linux/ubuntu/ jammy-security main restricted  
deb-src https://ftp.snt.utwente.nl/pub/os/linux/ubuntu/ jammy-security universe main multiverse restricted  
deb https://ftp.snt.utwente.nl/pub/os/linux/ubuntu/ jammy-security universe  
deb https://ftp.snt.utwente.nl/pub/os/linux/ubuntu/ jammy-security multiverse
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question with the *exact* error messages you get, and the content of `/etc/apt/sources.list` and `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/*`.

Comment: exact error is in Dutch, i tried to translate as best as possible.
i use default sources.list. `deb https://ftp.snt.utwente.nl/pub/os/linux/ubuntu/ jammy main restricted` for example.

Comment: you can rerun with `LANG=c apt-get upgrade`  to get language in English. Furthermore, is that the *only* source line in sources.list?

Answer (score 0):

After some trying ans searching... no luck
just removed python3, and 158 packages.
and start over...